# Cant see method : SendEmailAsync in UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am implementing Password Reset in asp.net. I was using this code :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
            return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
        }

        var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", 
    new { UserId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", 
    "Please reset your password by clicking here: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");        
        return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

From this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity#examine-the-code-in-appstartidentityconfigcs

I got error :

> 'UserManager' does not contain a definition for
>   'SendEmailAsync' and no extension method 'SendEmailAsync' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'UserManager' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What did i miss ?

Comment: Update the library that has the class UserManager. Probably you don't have the version that contains this method

Comment: Its from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and version is : <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />

Comment: You are mixing up identity versions. The linked documentation is for MVC 5 while `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` is for ASP.Net Core. Confirm what version of asp.net you are developing against.

Comment: I am not sure i understand. User manager object is from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity package :
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

Comment: There are different versions of Identity Framework that both have UserManager, but not with all the same members. They are very similar APIs but are completely different frameworks

Comment: Oh i see, what should i do to fix it ?

Comment: Well first we need to know what version of asp.net you are using?

Comment: ASP.NET Core MVC (netcoreapp2.0)

Comment: Here is the same documentation for asp.net core. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?tabs=aspnetcore2x you will see that they have different methods. You were referring to the wrong version API

Comment: i dont get this at all, why is so hard in this tutorials to put whole code, so people can see what to include and stuff like that

Comment: Could you share us a simple project which could reproduce your issue?